Computation question for ANOVA with matrices
I'm currently studying for finals and have come across this question that I'm having trouble approaching. The linear regression model is defined as always (in this particular scenario with 2 covariates) :
$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1X_{i1}+\beta_2X_{i2}+\epsilon_{i}$ where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$
The following is given in the question:
$
 (X^TX)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
3.80427 &-0.38533 &-1.47616 \\
-0.38533 & 0.14379 &-0.00997 \\
-1.47616 & -0.0097 & 0.86774
\end{bmatrix} 
$
$
(Y^TX)=\begin{bmatrix}
739\\
2304.4
\\1282.8
\end{bmatrix}
$
$
(Y^TY)=100485
$
I'm being asked to construct an ANOVA table to test whether the covariates explain the response variable (with $\alpha=0.05$). I understand what to do perfectly (simple F-test, coming from my MSR/MSE), however I'm not sure how to find SST or SSR
SSE can be found easily with the following manipulation:
$
\begin{align}
SSE = \sum(e_{i})^2=(Y-\hat{Y})^T(Y-\hat{Y})\\
=(Y^T-\hat{Y}^T)(Y-\hat{Y})\\=Y^TY-Y^T\hat{Y}\\=Y^TY-Y^TX\beta\\=Y^TY-\beta^TX^TY
\end{align}
$
where $\beta$ can be found in the usual manner. The problem comes with finding either SSR or SST, as they all require the matrix of $Y$ to be explicitly defined (from what I can see). Does anyone have any hints on solving such a problem?
